# React | React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to update a value in the store ONLY ONCE AT FIRST OPENING when the page is first opened using react hook. For this, I make the second parameter of useEffect '[]' empty list. Nothing prevents it from working, but I get a warning from ESLint rules: **React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'changeCount'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps**. How do I remove this warning?

```
const App = ({UserStore:{setCount, count}}) => {
  const changeCount = () => {
    setCount();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    changeCount();
  },[])

  return (
  ..
  )}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this syntax to remove this `eslint` warning before your dependency array like this:

```
const App = ({UserStore:{setCount, count}}) => {
const changeCount = () => {
    setCount();
}

useEffect(() => {
    changeCount();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
},[])

return (
  ..
)}
```

Comment: You shouldn't disable ALL warnings ever. Specify which warning to disable it, and ideally leave a comment in code doing so as well, especially for a warning where the docs claim code triggering it is always wrong...

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom hook ...

```
export const useMountEffect = handler => useEffect(handler, []);
```

Consume it like

```
useMountEffect(() => {
  changeCount();
});
```

Not only you'll get rid of this warning ... but it'll be more clear that this effect will only be executed `onMount` ...

Answer (score 2):

`changeCount` is a function that is not a `setState` or hooks. Since you use it in `useEffect` React will warn you. For the reason why it warns you read [this article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#dont-lie-to-react-about-dependencies)

Some of the answers above suggest you disable the checking, and I recommend diable only the one you are working on. However, normally you don't need to worry about a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Move `changeCount` inside `useEffect`

```
const App = ({UserStore:{setCount, count}}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const changeCount = () => {
      setCount();
    }

    changeCount();
  },[])

  return (
  ..
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

> Fix eslint config "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"

### Answer

It is eslint error with hook, so how about fix eslint config like

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    // ...
    "react-hooks"
  ],
  "rules": {
    // ...
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error", // Checks rules of Hooks
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off" // Checks effect dependencies
  }
}
```

But It can make your hook be wrong action, So the other way you can use `/* eslint-disable */`

### Reference

[01. Rules of Hooks - React Document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Comment: I think even suggesting to disable that whole rule is a terrible idea.

Comment: I think so :) But it is just some way to solve it